# Criteria of divisibility by $8$ of Large Integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any number greater than $1000$, how can we prove that it is divisible by $8$ if and only if $8$ divides the last $4$ digits of that number.

( e.g. $8\mid 98736$ as $8\times 1092 = 8736$ ).

Comment: **Hnt** $\,\ 2\mid 10\,\Rightarrow\, \color{}{2^{\Large 3}\mid \color{#c00}{10^{\Large 3}}},\ $ so $\ 2^{\Large 3}\!\mid a\!+\!\color{#c00}{10^{\Large 3}}b \iff 2^{\Large 3}\!\mid a\ \ \ $

Comment: Note above that $a$ is the "units" digit in radix $1000$ so the test is analogous to testing divisibility by $2$ or $5$ in radix $10$ by testing only the units digit. This works for any factor of the radix.

Answer (score 3):

Let's write a number $N\geq1000$ number as $N=1000a+b$ (where $b<1000$). Then, 
$$8|b\implies 8|(b+8\cdot(125a)) \implies 8|b+1000a\implies 8|N$$
In your example, $N=98736=98*1000+736$, and since both $736$ and $98*1000$ are divisible by $8$, so is their sum, $N$.

---

Note that I only showed the theorem for the last 3 digits - I assume that's what you meant, and if not, the above shows the stronger form of your theorem. Try fiddling around with it and see if you understand why it's true for the last 4 digits, too.

Comment: yes, it's because there is one factor 2 baked into each 10 and there are three 10 factors in 1000 and $2^3=8$.

Comment: That is correct. With that, it can be generalized to: a number whose last $n$ digits are divisible by $2^n$ is itself divisible by $2^n$

Answer (score 0):

In fact you only need the last three digits of the number. This is because $8$ divides $1000$.

Answer (score 0):

The criteria can even be refined a little if we want.

Let's write the number $n=1000a+100b+c$ with $b\in\{0,..,9\}$ and $c\in\{0,..,99\}$.

If $b$ is even then $b=2k$ so $n\equiv 8(125a)+8(25k)+c\equiv c\pmod 8$

If $b$ is odd then $b=2k+1$ so $n\equiv 8(125a)+8(25k)+100+c\equiv 100+c\equiv 8\times 12+4+c\equiv 4+c\pmod 8$

> So when you have a number $n=1000a+100b+c$ :
>
> - if the hundreds digit $b$ is even then $n$ is divisible by $8$ if $c$ is.
> - if the hundreds digit $b$ is odd then $n$ is divisible by $8$ if $c+4$  is.

For $n=98736$ we look at $...736\to$ $7$ is odd and $36+4=40$ is divisible by $8$ so $n$ is divisible by $8$.

This is a gain of efficiency to look only (almost) at the last $2$ digits.