# So I have a question. I got a number in 6*1*8 where the total number has to be divisible with 9 and not 8. How do I find * (the two unknown digits)?

Tags: education

I kinda know the answer from just guessing and trying to input different numbers but I probably should use something like divisibility rule of 3 or 9 or something but I struggle.
Answer I got:

- 60 138,
- 62 118,
- 63 108,
- 63 198,
- 64 188,
- 65 178,
- 67 158,
- 68 148,
- 69 138,

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the digits must be divisible by  9 for the whole number to be divisible by 9.

The last 3 digits of the number must be divisible by 8 , for the whole number to be divisible by 8.

Comment: Sum must be divisible by $9$ not necessarily equal. The criteria of division by $8$ can be refined a little since last three digits are $100+c$ in this case $c+4$ should be divisible by $8$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2174862/399263).